# Apache 2.4 / mod_wsgi / Flask / Ubuntu 16.04 on EC2 stops working after a few hours

Tags: apache, flask, amazon-ec2, mod-wsgi

I have a nasty bug in a Flask web application running on Apache on an EC2 instance running Ubuntu 16.04. Every few hours (3-5?) the Flask app stop working--with no errors in the Apache logs-- while other directories continue to function fine.

- For clients, requests to the Flask server are never fulfilled (just timeout, with no informative 503, etc.)
- Machine resources are fine according to `htop`
- Apache has plenty of idle workers / threads according to `server-status`; Flask app is not resource intensive and there are only ~5-10 users at a time
- I don't get any errors in `/var/log/apache2/error.log` (many things get logged here from the Flask app before the app stops working)

`sites-enabled/default-ssl.conf` reads (`telephone-flask` is the name of the Flask app):

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
  <VirtualHost _default_:443>
     #WSGIDaemonProcess flaskapp threads=8
     WSGIScriptAlias /telephone-flask /var/www/telephone-flask/telephone-flask.wsgi
    <Directory telephone-flask>
      WSGIScriptReloading On
      WSGIProcessGroup telephone-flask
      WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
      Order deny,allow
      Allow from all
    </Directory>`
  </VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

I am using the `mpm_events` module with he following settings:

```
<IfModule mpm_event_module>
    StartServers 8
    MinSpareThreads 75
    MaxSpareThreads 250
    ThreadLimit 64
    ThreadsPerChild 25
    MaxRequestWorkers 300
    MaxConnectionsPerChild 0
</IfModule>
```

In case it's relevant, I have the elastic IP of the instance behind a dynamic DNS service, but I don't see how that would affect the Flask app but not other things served by Apache.

Where else might this problem be logged? Is there something wrong with my Apache configuration? Is there something weird happening with networking because it's on EC2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your configuration is incorrect in a number of ways. Try using:

```
WSGIRestrictEmbedded On

<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
  <VirtualHost _default_:443>
    WSGIDaemonProcess telephone-flask threads=5 request-timeout=60
    WSGIScriptAlias /telephone-flask /var/www/telephone-flask/telephone-flask.wsgi process-group=telephone-flask application-group=%{GLOBAL}
    <Directory /var/www/telephone-flask>
      Require all granted
    </Directory>
    LogLevel info
  </VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

Most important thing here is getting it to correctly use daemon mode and adding the `request-timeout=60` option.

Most likely your application is locking up and Apache is eventually just killing its child worker processes.

The `request-timeout` will force a restart of daemon process when requests get stuck for too long as well (average of 60 seconds across all threads). When this occurs, it will dump out Python stack traces of where your code is getting stuck.

But then it also may now run fine as well, since the incorrect path to `Directory` meant `WSGIApplicationGroup` was ignored. It you were using third party C extensions for Python, there was a chance they were deadlocking if they weren't implemented to work in sub interpreters properly.

One final important thing. Don't use mod_wsgi package from Ubuntu. It is usually ancient, is not supported and may have bugs in it. It is possible that the Python stack traces will not be dumped out correctly depending on which old version they have. Compile mod_wsgi yourself from source code. Easiest way is using `pip` method as explained in:

- https://pypi.org/project/mod_wsgi/